# Faster alternative for grepping within a loop

Tags: string, shell

I would like to extract all those lines from a large text file (*infile2.txt*) that match the lines found in a medium-sized text file (*infile1.txt*). Correct matches shall occur from the beginning of the line. The three lines that follow the match in *infile2.txt* shall be extracted as well.

The following code will do just that, but at an agonizingly slow pace:

```
for i in $(cat infile1.txt); do cat infile2.txt | grep -A3 ^$i >> results.txt; done &
```

I presume that the loading of *infile2.txt* during every iteration of the loop constitutes the bottleneck. What code alternatives would you employ to speed up the string extraction?

Comment: Look at the `-f` flag to `grep`. Also don't pipe files to `grep` just list them on the command line. `grep` can take files directly.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thank you for the suggestion. Yes, code such as `grep -A3 -f infile2.txt infile1.txt >> results.txt &` does speed up the string extraction. It still seems a bit sluggish, though. Any additional suggestions?

Comment: You inverted your arguments there it looks like but that's not really relevant. No specific suggestions. You'd have to see what is taking the time. If the input is plain strings then using `-F` (for fixed strings instead of regexes) might help. The `--mmap` option might also help.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes, the option `-F` (i.e., matching fixed strings instead of regular expressions) was the key to speeding up code execution. Thank you.

Comment: @EtanReisner - if you move your answer to an answer, it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `-f` (patterns from file) flag to `grep` like this

```
grep -A3 -f infile1.txt infile2.txt > result.txt
```

will likely help quite a bit.

If the input is plain strings (rather than regexes) then using the `-F` (for fixed strings) might also help.

The `--mmap` option might also be of some use depending on various factors.

Beyond that the causes of slow searching are likely down to file size, disk speed, etc.